# Meteor-down load testing

Tags: meteor, load-testing

I am trying to make load/stress test to my website. I am using meteor-down. I wrote the test file my_load_test.js

```
meteorDown.init(function(Meteor) {
    var title = "question"
    var description = "description"
    var tags = ["javascript"]
    let data = {
        title,
        description,
        tags
    }
    Meteor.call('createQuestion', data, function(err, result) {
        Meteor.kill();
    });

});

meteorDown.run({
    concurrency: 10,
    url: "http://localhost:3000/discussions",
    key: 'mykey',
    auth: {
        userIds: ['fL6pirusvokposvwX', 'P4DNubMrEQsEQvNX2', 'AN3xqZHaQNmJ4nghe', 'v9XWPKQ7BapnNGY2F']
    }
});
```

But when i run in the terminal, only a time stamp is printed [timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6crG.png)

or some times an error occurs even though I dont change the test file
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07zxG.png)

Comment: Hello, I am having the same issue. Could you solve it? I wonder how you give userIds with auth, but not the password. how will that work? Thank you